# if(!getline(std::cin, str1)) break; what does this condition check?

Tags: c++, loops, getline

I have this code:

```
 while (true){
 std::string cmdline;
 if (!std::getline( std::cin, cmdline )) break;

 std::istringstream cmdstream( cmdline );
 std::string cmd;
 cmdstream >> cmd;
 ...}
```

What does the if condition check and why does it end in an endless loop if I leave out the `!`?

Answer (score 3):

Since C++ inserts an implicit comparison to zero, this line

```
if (!std::getline( std::cin, cmdline )) break;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!std::getline( std::cin, cmdline ) != 0) break;
```

or simply

```
if (std::getline( std::cin, cmdline ) == 0) break;
```

`std::getline` returns the stream on which it is called. The stream gets converted to `bool` or to `void*`, depending on the version of C++ library. The converted value becomes zero when the end of the input is reached. That's why the loop ends when there are no additional input to read.

Another way to write the same code would be as follows:

```
std::string cmdline;
while (std::getline( std::cin, cmdline )) {
    std::istringstream cmdstream( cmdline );
    std::string cmd;
    cmdstream >> cmd;
    ...
}
```

This lets you put the ending condition into the loop header, at the expense of declaring `cmdline` outside the loop.

Comment: "`std::getline` returs zero when the end of the input is reached" It actually returns the stream itself where it is then contextually converted to `bool` using its boolean conversion operator. `std::getline == 0` is a compile time error (in >=C++11), in C++03 the conversion to `void*` occurs which is then compared to the null pointer constant `0` making it valid.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for the comment! I didn't want to get into the small details here, but I guess there's no way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline` returns a reference to the stream passed as the first argument, which is `std::cin` in your case. This means that your

```
if (!std::getline( std::cin, cmdline )) break;
```

is equivalent to

```
std::getline( std::cin, cmdline );
if (!std::cin) break;
```

The last line is equivalent to

```
if (std::cin.fail()) break;
```

which will break out of cycle if `getline` raised `failbit` flag in the stream. This happens if I/O error or end-of-stream condition prevented `getline` from reading anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since according to:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

The return parameter is the input stream which in this case in std::cin, thus if the std::cin input is empty then the return is empty.

Basically, did the user input anything ?